# How to get position fixed when the user scrolls down

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have an horizontal menu inside the rest of the body..

I want to make this menu floating with position:fixed when i scroll the page down

How is that supposed to be ? :)
Thanx!

Comment: Why dont you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I guess he want's that when a user scrolls say around 100px or 200px down the page the fixed bar should appear right?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="bar">I am a navigation bar.</div>
```

```css
div#bar{
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: green;
}
```

Here the horizontal bar will stick to the bottom.

Comment: @AhmedNefzaoui - So what is your question?